# What is the difference between Drupal 7.9 and 7.34 (current stable)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am currently reviewing a Drupal site I am taking on for a client.  My first task will be to make sure it's all up to date as the site was hacked recently.

Currently it is on version 7.9 - what it is recommending me is 7.34.  7.34 is the currently recommended stable release as per the Drupal site.  What is this 7.9 version?  Was it an old beta or dev version? What version should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7.9 is not "Drupal 7.90". This version is older than Drupal 7.34.

I recommend you to upgrade the Drupal core from 7.9 to 7.34 for performance and security reasons. Check first if is possible. Some developers hacks the Drupal Core, which is a very bad practice.

If you want to see all the changelog, you can see this article: https://www.drupal.org/node/3060/release?api_version%5B%5D=103

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7.9 was an official stable release back in Oct 26, 2011.
You should use the most recent Drupal release (currently 7.34).

In addition, since you've mentioned the site was hacked, it would be really pointless just to upgrade the Core, since you should upgrade all the modules as well, but firstly - you should take care of potential threat left from the previous attack.

Look at the standard procedure of the steps required: [Your Drupal website has a backdoor](http://drupal.geek.nz/blog/your-drupal-website-has-backdoor)